# Tolerating SQL errors (orderby not in distinct, select not in group by) in MySQL 5.7.13 vs 5.7.11

Tags: mysql, group-by, syntax, mysql-5.7, distinct

This question is related to the following 2 SQL errors (line breaks added by me)

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005):
Expression #2 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'auitool2014.a.prog' which is not in SELECT list;
this is incompatible with DISTINCT


MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): 
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'H.C51' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

My problem is simple to describe, even without posting the original SQL. I have a Mysql `5.7.11-log` server running on Windows in which I can `SELECT A,B GROUP BY A` and `SELECT DISTINCT A,B ORDER BY C` without any problem. Yes, **this is wrong from the SQL point of view**.

But it works and customers are happy. It will <strike>never be fixed</strike> be fixed in the future.

We just installed a fresh standard Mysql `5.7.13-log` on Linux using Yum. Now all queries containing such errors break.

I have looked around and it seems that [Mysql team did some work](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79134) about improper `GROUP BY`s. I have tried to [disable full group bys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37248560/471213) but then I am left with the distinct issue.

I have also tried to *replicate* part of the Mysql configuration from the Windows box but returned again to both issues.

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

I just want to know how do I tell the new Mysql 5.7.13 to behave exactly like the (bugged?) version 5.7.11. We will try to install the exact 5.7.11 from Yum but it could take a considerable while. So to be more clear: how do I get rid of those two errors, **humbly given that the SQL statements need to be eventually fixed**?

Comment: Why not fix the queries now? Seems like a good time to do that!

Comment: Do you really want to know why it is impossible? Those queries must be signed-off by a non-IT person, a lawyer, who simply says "they worked on the previous version". Hahah please don't ask me the full story, it's a coding horror story :-)

Comment: Rolled back to Mysql 5.6. The original application worked on Mysql 5.1 by the way. It is a few years old application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you are saying:

5.7.5 changelog says

"Queries of the form SELECT DISTINCT col1 ... ORDER BY col2 qualify as forbidden by SQL2003 (hidden ORDER BY columns combined with DISTINCT), but were not rejected with the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode enabled. "

Perhaps you should plea to bugs.mysql.com for a 'mode' to violate SQL2003 on the grounds that there is no way to get what you want.